# CSS3 Translate3d : Element still be clickable even it's out of the scene on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, css-transforms

I made a big cube with transform3D, and I put 6 DIVs,  on each side of that cube which are all clickable.

And to make the users to feel like they're in this cube, I move the centroid of the cube to the center of the scene with the following css tricks:

```
TweenMax.set(cubeContainer, {perspective:500});
TweenMax.set(cube, {z : 500});
```

And the user is able to drag the cube to make it spin.

When the rotationX and rotationY of that cube is 0, the back side is supposed to be invisible and no any mouse event will be fired due to the perspective settings.

It works fine on Chrome.

And on Firefox, it is invisible but firing mouse events.

How would that happen?

It still not works even if I set the "backface-visibility" to "hidden".

Any ideas to fix it?

Thanks.

---

Update

I've added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2o3cxer/7/)

You can see that the shape is still clickable( just click the center of the container ) even if it's totally out of the scene.

But it's totally vanished on Chrome. Is this the bug of Firefox?

Or there's something need to be fixed in my code?

Comment: Try to add `display:none`

Comment: But it supposed to be set automatically by the browser. The div is already invisible because it's behind the camera.

Comment: It's not invisible, it's just transformed. Object exist. it's like `opacity:0`.

Comment: It should be invisible because it's out of the scene. I'm not sure how it works in CSS3, but there's some algorithm running background in Flash to determine whether the object is displaying or not due to the distance between the object and the camera. And the perspective is the distance of the camera to any object at (0,0,0). Assuming there's a object A at (0,0,0) in the container, and the perspective of the container is 500px. If we move A to (0,0,-600), it will be invisible because it is behind the camera. At the same time, the mouse events of the object should be all disabled.